# xtext link between infix notation to non-infix operations

Tags: xtext

Addition (function add) is usually represented by an infix operator '+'.

Does xtext have functionality to handle infix operations?

Link an infix operation to its function. For '+' linked to 'add'?

**Update**

I am defining a grammar for an expression but Xbase is too general and contain elements that I do not need.

The grammar contain a `+` operator. The function `add` is defined. Does xtext provide support to link `a + b` to `add(a, b)` so that validation only need to be implemented for `add` and is also used for `+`

Comment: can you please give more context?

Comment: did you read on xtext and expressions?

Comment: did you have a look at xbase?

Comment: sorry will only look now again, was a bit preoccupied